# How can I get the uri from the fetch?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to cache images in the app, so they can load faster. The tutorial I found used `FileSystem` from Expo, but I'm not using expo, so I found `react-native-file-access` instead. After mounting, the code should check if the image exists, if not, download the image. I've tried but I can't seem to make it work.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-native';
import shorthash from 'shorthash';
import {Dirs, FileSystem} from 'react-native-file-access';

export default class CacheImage extends Component {
  state = {
    source: null,
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const {uri} = this.props;
    const name = shorthash.unique(uri);
    const path = `${Dirs.CacheDir}/${name}`;

    const image = await FileSystem.exists(path);
    if (image.exists) {
      this.setState({
        source: {
          uri: image.uri,
        },
      });
      return;
    }

    /* Download image if one doesn't exist */
    const newImage = await FileSystem.fetch(uri, {path: path})
      .then(response => {
        JSON.stringify(response);
      })
      .then(data => data);

    this.setState({
      source: {
        uri: newImage.uri,
      },
    });
    console.log('URI: ', this.state.source);
  };

  render() {
    return <Image style={this.props.style} source={this.state.source} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: The first `then()` has no return so `data` in next then will be undefined and that would make `newImage` be undefined

Comment: What am I supposed to return?

Comment: Basic rule is you need to return something if there is another then() in the chain that expects to receive something when it is called. Otherwise will just get `undefined` returned. Check for yourself and try logging data in last then and also log newImage before setState

Answer (score 0):

I returned the `response` without the `JSON.stringify()`.

```
const newImage = await FileSystem.fetch(uri, {path: path})
      .then(response => {
        return response;
      });

this.setState({
      source: {
        uri: newImage.url,
      },
    });
```

And I also removed the second `.then()` because I still get the `url` without adding it.

Answer (score -1):

the problem come from here

```
const newImage = await FileSystem.fetch(uri, {path: path})
      .then(response => {
        JSON.stringify(response);
      })
      .then(data => data);
```

you forget to return when use {}

```
const newImage = await FileSystem.fetch(uri, {path: path})
      .then(response => {
        return JSON.stringify(response);
      })
      .then(data => data);
```

Comment: `{"headers":{"..."},"ok":true,"redirected":false,"status":200,"statusText":"","url":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/peza-e3455.appspot.com/o/images%2Fproducts%2Fbmw-m3-m4-engine-3.0-inline-twin-turbo.png?alt=media&token=0474875e-563b-4832-aa82-cd515b8c8e3f"}`. This is what I get from `newImage`, how do I only assign the `url` to `source`?

Comment: I've found my solution. I returned the `response` without the `JSON.stringify()`, to pick out the `url`. Thanks.